# In stress-strain diagrams, why is the dependent axis ($y$) used to represent stress and the independent axis ($x$) to represent strain?

Tags: conventions, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

why this convention is used

[image]

despite the fact that strain is influenced by stress (cause -> stress, effect -> strain)

Answer (score 5):

Because [the equipment used to measure stress-strain curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_testing_machine) works by applying a strain that increases linearly with time and measuring the stress. The strain is the independent variable.

The problem with measuring strain as a function of stress is that it's not uncommon for the stress to fall with increasing strain once a yield point is reached, like this:

[image: Stress-strain curve]

[Picture from this page](https://www.smlease.com/entries/mechanical-design-basics/stress-strain-curve-diagram/)

If you used a linearly increasing stress your measurements would miss this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the very good answer by John Rennie, a couple of other notes:

1. You can choose whatever axis orientation you deem appropriate, it is based on conventions, and people often do what other people do without thinking too deeply about it. This simplifies (and is actually the basis of) communication.
2. Everyone draws $F(x)$ diagrams, so what should be strange about $\sigma(\epsilon)$ diagrams?
3. What is cause and what is effect is often undecidable on this most basic level. In technology it is most often a matter of what variable is controlled. A CNC milling machine for example does not (primarily) control force to cut the workpiece, because this would require a complicated calculation (involving tool shape, Young's modulus, plastic properties, possible defects, heat conduction, axis/tool speed...) to determine the right force, and any small irregularity in the material would then cause the cutter to be drawn in and produce an undesired shape. Controlling position limits any undesired movement (even though it cannot prevent it completely). On the other hand, the motor that drives the axis of the CNC machine is often controlled on the lowest level by providing a certain set point electric current (which somehow results in force control). It would be much too unreliable/unstable to calculate beforehand (i.e. open-loop/uncontrolled) the voltage needed to apply to the motor, because there is a complicated relationship between voltage and motor force (involving Ohmic resistance, induction, load, speed, temperature...). So the overall control guides position, but the desired current this controller provides is fed into the underlying current/force controller which adjusts voltage until it satisfies the given current.

As John Rennie already emphasized, a testing machine controls position (strain), not least because if the workpiece fails (tears), force control would result in very fast motion that bears the risk of damaging the machine itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to emphasize that stress is a intensive physical quantity and strain is a extensive physical quantity.　I prefer to graph the stress on the vertical axis and the strain on the horizontal axis, taking the intensive physical quantity on the vertical axis and the extensive physical quantity on the horizontal axis.

Comment: The same approach is taken for P–V and T–S diagrams in thermodynamics, which also show [conjugate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_\(thermodynamics\)) like stress and strain.